# Different API Host with gradle and android

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I was wondering if it is possible to provide a different API Host per build using gradle.  Ideally I would like to access the constant through my code the same so when I do a gradle build, it builds the release.apk to point to http://example.com and the debug.apk to point to http://debug.example.com.

I have achieved this using the following:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfig "public final static String API_HOST = \"http://debug.example.com\";"
    }

    release {
        buildConfig "public final static String API_HOST = \"https://example.com\";"
    }
}
```

However that seems pretty dirty

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to use `buildConfigField`:

```
buildTypes {
  debug {
    buildConfigField 'String', 'API_HOST', '"https://debug.example.com"'
  }

  release {
    buildConfigField 'String', 'API_HOST', '"https://example.com"'
  }
}
```

You would then refer to it in your code via `BuildConfig.API_HOST`

Answer (score 4):

I think a better alternative with today's Gradle features is to specify both `productFlavors` and `buildTypes` (example below).

The buildTypes control what certificate I sign with, and whether Proguard is run.

The productFlavors control the intended environment, which includes custom resources, as well as a different package name so I can install them both side by side.

Then I configure my server address in strings.xml for each variant and load it at runtime.

```
src/dev/res/values/strings.xml
src/staging/res/values/strings.xml
```

strings.xml example from the "dev" variant:

```
<string name="config_url">http://com.example.debug</string>
```

build.gradle snippet:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        packageName "com.example.dev"
    }

    staging {
        packageName "com.example.staging"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix " debug"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    release {
        // A release build runs Proguard, and signs with a release certificate
        zipAlign true
        runProguard true
        proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you do this if you have a google-services.json file that need the same package name everywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up speaking to one of the gradleware engineers about this.... My initial solution is the correct way.  Google/Gradle will be improving this in the future.

To add multiple values you separate the the strings with comas.

Comment: Thanks, how do you reference API_HOST? Do you need to have a buildConfig class already set up?

Comment: Gradle (at least for android, using visual studio) will create a BuildConfig.java.  From there you just reference the the constant.

ie callEndPoint(BuildConfig.API_HOST);

Comment: Thanks! When I add constants this way, however, I'm not seeing them show up in BuildConfig. Any ideas?

Comment: are you using android studio? if not running a gradle build from the command line should trigger the BuildConfig.java to reflect your changes... *maybe*

Comment: can't seem to edit my above comment... i meant "ANDROID studio" not "VISUAL studio"... lol