# Resources$NotFoundException when using Robolectric with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric, build.gradle

I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.peterfriese.de/android-testing-with-robolectric/) on setting up Robolectric to test my Android Gradle project.

I keep hitting this error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: no such label com.mypackage.dev:string/app_name
```

By downloading the sample project from the tutorial I've established that the problem is my `productFlavors` (dev, staging, production).  Adding flavors to the working sample project causes the same issue.  You can see an outline of my [build.gradle in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21035503/112705).

I've seen various answers (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21186622/112705)) which suggest I need to specify the `sourceSets` for each flavor.  I've tried lots of combinations but can't quite get it correct.  Can anybody help?

The other thing confusing me is that all the Robolectric samples I've seen seem to be specifying the sourceSets and dependencies for "instrumentTest", even though the Robolectric tests are always only in the "test" folder.  In my case I already have Robotium tests in the instrumentTest folder, and I don't see why I would need to add Robolectric dependencies for the Robotium code.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem (resources not found) and found a solution on the robolectric source. There is a setter for PackageName, so in my custom test runner I set the package name before returning the manifest. Something like:

```
@Override protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
    String manifestProperty = System.getProperty("android.manifest");
    if (config.manifest().equals(Config.DEFAULT) && manifestProperty != null) {
        String resProperty = System.getProperty("android.resources");
        String assetsProperty = System.getProperty("android.assets");
        AndroidManifest manifest = new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(manifestProperty), Fs.fileFromPath(resProperty),
                Fs.fileFromPath(assetsProperty));
        manifest.setPackageName("com.mypackagename");
        return manifest;
    }
    return super.getAppManifest(config);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Robolectric fixed this issue in version 3.0. So just use latest version of Robolectric with defined constans param in `@Config` annotation.

```
@Config(
        sdk = 21,
        manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
        constants = BuildConfig.class
)

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
```

Also, one important item - for correct Robolectric work your `applicationId` in `gradle.build` should be equals to `package` in `AndroidManifest`. Usage of `applicationIdSuffix` doesn't affect Robolectric.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by specifying 'packageName' in your @Config so that it becomes:

```
@Config(
        sdk = 21, 
        manifest="src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
        constants = BuildConfig.class,
        packageName = "com.mypackage" //this is whatever value is your AndroidManifest.xml at <manifest ... package="com.mypackage".../>
)
```